# Any idea why my LED fails to operate with the if statement

Tags: programming

I have tried several workarounds without success.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
float tempC;
int tempPin = 0;// BS E D4 D5 D6 D7
int buzzer = 4;
int LED =2;
LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
unsigned char i;
void setup()
{
lcd.begin(16, 2);
lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
lcd.print("Temp        C ");
pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
pinMode(buzzer,OUTPUT);//initialize the buzzer pin as an output
}
void loop()
{
tempC = getTemperature();
lcd.setCursor(6, 0); // Display Temperature in C
lcd.print(tempC);
delay(500);
}
float getTemperature()
{
int tempReading = analogRead(tempPin); // This is OK
double tempK = log(1000000.0 * ((1024.0 / tempReading - 1)));
//Temperature in Kelvin
tempK = 1 / (0.001129148 + (0.000234125 + (0.0000000876741 * tempK * tempK )) * tempK );
return (tempK - 273.15);

if (tempC>0)
digitalWrite(LED,HIGH);
else
digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
}
```

Comment: two possible reasons ... 1. the led is incorrectly connected and it does not light no matter what you do ... 2. the `if` statement evaluates to a result that does not turn on the led

Comment: I edited your question and used the `{}` button for code formatting, but your code doesn't have any indentation. You need to edit your code to use proper indentation. Without that it is very hard to read.

Comment: Your code to look at temperatures is messed up. You have a global variable `tempC`. The function `getTemperature()` doesn't change the value of `tempC`, but it uses it to decide if the LED should be lit or not. That means that that function will make it's decision based on the previous value of tempC.

Comment: You should rewrite your `getTemperature()` function to put the Celsius temp into a temporary variable, use that to decide what to do with the LED, and then return the temporary value. That way `getTemperature()` will set the LED based on the just-calculated temp value, not on the old, now-out-of-date temp reading.

Comment: Also note that if tempReading is 0, your code will crash with a divide-by-zero error. You should add some error handling code to deal with that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LED fails to operate with the if statement because calling the `return` statement [Terminates a function and returns a value from a function to the calling function, if desired](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/control-structure/return/). Try your sketch with the `return` statement as the "last thing" in the function.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

float tempC;
int tempPin = 0; // BS E D4 D5 D6 D7
int buzzer = 4;
int LED = 2;
LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
unsigned char i;

void setup() { 
  lcd.begin(16, 2); 
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0); 
  lcd.print("Temp C "); 
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(buzzer,OUTPUT);//initialize the buzzer pin as an output
} 

void loop() { 
  tempC = getTemperature(); 
  lcd.setCursor(6, 0); // Display Temperature in C 
  lcd.print(tempC); 
  delay(500); 
} 

float getTemperature() { 
  int tempReading = analogRead(tempPin); // This is OK 
  double tempK = log(1000000.0 * ((1024.0 / tempReading - 1))); //Temperature in Kelvin 
  tempK = 1 / (0.001129148 + (0.000234125 + (0.0000000876741 * tempK * tempK )) * tempK ); 
  if (tempC>0) digitalWrite(LED,HIGH); else digitalWrite(LED, LOW); 
  return (tempK - 273.15);
}
```

Comment: If that code fix doesn't work I suggest you write a sketch that forces the LED to high, delays, forces it to low, delays, and loops. See if the LED flashes. If not, you have a hardware problem with the wiring of your LED. if it does work, then you have a problem with reading your temperature sensor and need to debug that part of your project.

Comment: Thank for the assistance and responses.  It does appear as if I have a physical problem of some kind.  My LED did function after shifting my breadboard a bit.  My temperature value constantly fluctuates sporadically and applying heat to my thermistor does not result in changes in the displayed temperature value. However the LED does illuminate when values rise above the limit which means the code is good.  Thanks again

Comment: Thanks Duncan.  You have been of great assistance and I certainly have a lot of learning to do and I look forward to it :)

Comment: One of the challenges of building Arduino projects is that you have to debug hardware and software problems. Work in steps. Hook up an LED, write a sketch that toggles the output pin on and off on a timer, and make sure that it works. After that, you know the LED works. Then integrate that working LED pin into your code, and if the code doesn't work, you know it's a code problem, not a hardware problem. If you get screw results from your code, add a bunch of Serial.println() statements displaying the values as you go along until you find your problem